# Prove or disprove a function is continuous

Tags: general-topology

I have a question, any help appericated :

Let $C=C(R,R)$ be the set of all continuous functions from the real line to itself. Let $\phi :C \times C \rightarrow C $ be the composition mapping defined by $ \phi (f,g)= f \circ g $( the function $f\circ g :R\rightarrow R $ is defined by $f\circ g (x)=f(g(x))$. Is $\phi$ continuous if $C$ is equipped with the pointwise convergence topology ( and $C \times C$ with the product topology)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composition is *discontinuous*, for there is no neighborhood $V$ of the $0$ function such that $\phi(V\times V)\subset@_{0}^{-1}\big((-1,+1)\big)$, yet $\phi(0,0)=0\in @_{0}^{-1}\big((-1,+1)\big)$. Here $@_0$ is the continuous map $C\to\Bbb R$ sending $f$ to $f(0)$.

Indeed, let $V$ be a neighborhood of $0$ : there exists (some integer positive integer $N$ and) $N$ points $x_1<\cdots<x_N\in\Bbb R$ and some $\epsilon >0$ such that
$$\lbrace\text{all continuous maps }f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\text{ such that }\forall i,~|f(x_i)|<\epsilon\rbrace\subset V$$
But there are obviously continuous functions in that elementary neighborhood that have $f(f(0))$ arbitrarily large, for instande $=1789$. Just take a continuous function $f$ that is piece-wise affine, $=0$ on all $x_i$, sends $0$ to $f(0)\in \Bbb R\setminus\lbrace x_1,\dots,x_N\rbrace$ and sends  $f(0)$ to $1789$. By definition, $f\in V$, yet $1789=f(f(0))=@_0\big(\phi(f,f)\big)\notin(-1,+1)$.

Comment: Can you explain more in details . thanks

Comment: Hi @henry, what do you want me to explain?

Comment: Thanks for reply. First I have trouble with the way you define $V$ and second in the end when you show that $1789=f(f(0))=@_0\big(\phi(f,f)\big)\notin(-1,+1)$.

Comment: For $V$, recall the standard basis for the product topology on $$\prod_{\Bbb R}\Bbb R$$, and intersect those sets with $C$.